# How to figure percentage change?

Tags: arithmetic

How would I figure out the percent a number change has?

Let's say I have this number: `88` and now it's `240`. How would I find out the percent raise it went up by?

Thanks.

Comment: $(240-88)/88\approx 173\%$

Comment: @J.M: I guess you forgot to multiply by $100$

Comment: 1.73 and 173% are the same thing, only in different "units".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percent change from one value (the "initial value") to another value (the "final value") is defined as

$\displaystyle \frac{(\mathrm{final \; value})\; - \; (\mathrm{initial \; value})}{\mathrm{initial \; value}} \; \times \;$ 100%

In your case, the computation is

$\displaystyle\frac{240 - 88}{88} \; \times$ 100%

$= \displaystyle \frac{152}{88} \; \times$ 100%

$= 1.72727... \; \times$ 100%

$= 172.727...$%

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on J. M.'s comment, note that you are actually looking for the solution $m$ of the equation
$$
\bigg(88 + \frac{m}{{100}}88 \bigg) = 240.
$$
The solution is 
$$
m = \bigg(\frac{{240 - 88}}{{88}}\bigg)100 = \bigg(\frac{{240}}{{88}} - 1\bigg)100 \approx 172.7.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\text{percentage value} = \frac{240-88}{88} \times 100$